# Jupyter "ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies: numpy:"

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I installed anaconda3 and python 3.9
Looks like anaconda3 is running with python 3.8.
When i installed first my jupyter on anaconda3 was working, but i did some changes in path/pythonpath and after that i am getting error on jupyter but it works fine on visual studio.
So far i have tried

1. Installing and uninstalling anaconda3 and python 3.9
2. Installing and uninstalling pandas and numpy

Below is output from jupyter for path and python path

```
import os
print("PYTHONPATH:", os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH'))
print("PATH:", os.environ.get('PATH'))
*******************************************************************
PYTHONPATH: C:\Users\sachi\anaconda3\python.exe
PATH: C:\Users\sachi\anaconda3;C:\Users\sachi\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\sachi\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\sachi\anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\sachi\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;c:\users\sachi\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages;C:\Python38\python.exe;C:\Users\sachi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Users\sachi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\;C:\Users\sachi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\sachi\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;c:\Python39;
*******************************************************************
```

Below is the error I get when I `import pandas as pd` in jupyter

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-7dd3504c366f> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd

~\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
     14 
     15 if missing_dependencies:
---> 16     raise ImportError(
     17         "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies)
     18     )

ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.8 from "C:\Users\sachi\anaconda3\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.20.3"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

Comment: Did you check the link given in the error message? https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Answer (score 1):

You can enter `pip uninstall pandas` first, Then enter `pip uninstall numpy`. These two step is to uninstall two modular. Ater that，you can enter `pip install pandas` and `pip install numpy` to reload two modular. That's how I solved the problem I just met

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).